# Using Strain Tensors to Recover Stress Tensors

Tags: mechanical-engineering, applied-mechanics, stresses, finite-element-method, solid-mechanics

#### Disclaimer:

I am very new to the field of mechanics, my background is in electrical engineering. I apologize in advance if anything is horribly wrong.
My references are:
"First Course in FEM, 4th Edition" by Daryl L Logan
"Theory of Elasticity, 3rd Edition" by S. Timoshenko and J.N. Goodier

#### Problem Statement

Let's say I have some three dimensional body which undergoes a deformation due to an internal stress profile. Call the undeformed state $ X $ and the deformed state $ X' $.

Assume that the undeformed state $ X $ has some internal stress profile and this stress profile is not in equilibrium. Call this initial stress profile $ S $. As time proceeds, the body relaxes until equilibrium is achieved. The deformed body in state $ X' $ ends up with some resulting stress profile $ S' $. A stress profile is constituted by a stress tensor at every point within the body.

Let's say that I have displacement equations describing the deformation. Concretely, I have three equations $ x' = d_1(x, y, z) $, $ y' = d_2(x, y, z) $, and $ z' = d_3(x, y, z) $. These fully describe how a point $ (x, y, z) $ moves to $ (x', y', z') $ under the deformation.

My primary goal is to use the displacement functions to estimate the stress tensor at every point in $ X $ which resulted in the observed deformation.

Here is my current approach:

1. Assuming small strain, we can relate the displacement equations to the entries in the strain tensors at every point. In particular, we know that $ \epsilon_x (x, y, z) = \frac{\partial d_1}{\partial x} (x, y, z) $, $ \epsilon_y (x, y, z) = \frac{\partial d_2}{\partial y} (x, y, z) $, etc.
2. Assuming linear elastic behavior, the stress and strain tensors at any point are linearly related. Thus we can say that $ \sigma = D \epsilon $ for some matrix $ D $. We can then use the strain tensors at every point, generated via the technique in step 1, to compute the stress tensors at every point which resulted in the observed deformation.

#### Questions

I'm not sure that this technique will produce a reasonable estimate of the stress tensors which caused the deformation. Step 2 relies on linear elasticity, but the deformation from $ X $ to $ X' $ is plastic. Do people think that this approach has any hope of estimating the stress profile of $ X $? Might it only produce reasonable results if the deformation is small?

If we knew the strain tensor, $ \epsilon $, at every point in a body which underwent a deformation, is there anything wrong with using $ \sigma = D \epsilon $ to recover the stress tensor, $ \sigma $, which caused the observed deformation?

Are there existing techniques to recover the stress state which resulted in an observed deformation? I've looked around and haven't found anything useful.

Edits:
Cleaned up the assumptions necessary for the 2 step process.

Comment: "*but the deformation from X to X′ is clearly plastic*" Why? What's the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: The question I am trying to answer is: Given a deformation of a body which occurred due to its internal stress state, can we measure the deformation and estimate the stress state which caused the deformation? I assume that the deformation from X to X' is plastic because the deformation is permanent. Maybe my use of the term 'plastic' is incorrect.

Comment: The term is correct; I want to know what motivates the assumption that the deformation is permanent. Are you just trying to consider the most general case, comprising both elastic and plastic deformation?

Comment: Ok, let me give you more context. Assume we have a metal workpiece, with some initial residual stress profile, which gets cut in a CNC machine. After the cut happens, the metal workpiece deforms (because of its residual stress profile). I'm trying to devise a numerical technique which can estimate the initial residual stress profile based on the deformation which occurred. I hope to devise a technique which is as general as possible.

Comment: Are you asking about the inverse elasticity problem, i.e., finding the set of loads, stresses and local material properties that produce a given set of displacements? [Example](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0020768396001527); [example](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0955799703000511).

Comment: Potentially. Let me take a look at those papers. Thank you for linking them!